# Understanding projectile motion formula with air resistance

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics

$\frac{dx}{dt} = v_x$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = v_y$

$\frac{dv_x}{dt} = -b|v|v_x$

$\frac{dv_y}{dt} = -g -b|v|v_y$

where $v = \sqrt{v^2_x+v^2_y}$ and $b$ is a drag constant

Why is it that the magnitude of the speed  (used in the last two equations) is multiplied with the speed in the $y$ and $x$ direction?

Comment: 2D quadratic drag was also considered in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28931/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your information, air resistance $\mathbf{f} \propto -v^{2}$ and 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{\mathbf{f}}{m} &= -bv^{2} \hat{\mathbf{v}} \\
                       &= -bv^{2} \frac{v_{x}\, \mathbf{i}+v_{y}\, \mathbf{j}}
                                       {|v|} \\
                       &= -b|v|(v_{x}\, \mathbf{i}+v_{y}\, \mathbf{j}) \\
            \mathbf{a} &= \mathbf{g}+\frac{\mathbf{f}}{m} \\
                       &= -b|v|v_{x}\, \mathbf{i}-(g+b|v|v_{y})\, \mathbf{j}
\end{align*}